# isotop jquery portfolio depending the number of items

Tags: jquery-isotope

Isotope was pre-installed with a Wordpress theme. Everything works, but by filtering, layout table is broken into, so there are holes. Apparently this is because the total number of items.

With filter: Pictures Gallery: http://www.lrguas.ch.preview02.net4all.ch/multimedias/

An idea of the problem?

Note that I have not limited the number of items to display.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Regards
Mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a simple solution: when examining your 8 filtered pictures items in Chrome's devtools, they have a different width, making some elements go to the next row, leaving a hole. If you make sure, each Isotope element has the same width, corresponding to your column width, then it should work.

International Friendship, Student Portfolio, Academic Life: 225 px

Bluche Region, Bulle Region, Social and Sport activities, Bluche campus facilities, Bulle Campus Facilities: 235px

So, first thing I'd try is to set the margins correct on the .work-item class or whatever element of each Isotope item determines the width for Isotope's layout engine, corresponding to your column width.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for you help. But I had looked at the CSS, but actually, if you look closer, I noticed a "margin-right" was to 0px, so I changed to 10px, and that's ok!'code'#content-full div:nth-child(4n) .work-item{
 margin-right:10px; /*avant 0px*/
}